# Check/uncheck checkboxes in the Laravel Nova Action Modal with BooleanGroup

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I use Laravel Nova. On a resource I have an Action. The `fields` method returns a `BooleanGroup` Field:

```
return [
    BooleanGroup::make('Tagss')->options(
        [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four'
        ]
    ),
];
```

Result:

[image]

I don't know how to pre-check checkboxes. Let's say 'two' should be checked when the modal loads, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [default](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#default-values) function. Set `true` for the default value

```
return [
    BooleanGroup::make('Tags')->options(
        [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four'
        ]
    )->default(function ($request) {
        return [
            'one' => false,
            'two' => true,
            'three' => false,
            'four' => false,
        ];
    }),
];
```